# How to view and edit machine code of for example an image file?

Tags: machine-code

If I understand correctly, every program and file is a combination of ones and zeros. Is there any way to view the machine code of a program? To view the data that the CPU processes? I can't seem to find any good answers on it.

Comment: Yes, the exact method varies. Some operating systems have debuggers that will show you the actual binary code, most have file viewers that will do the same thing. Windows includes a "debug" command which can be used to open a hex editor to show the contents, for example.

Comment: When you say "image file", you mean like a picture? I ask because unfortunately "image file" can also mean "snapshot of a disk", especially when dealing with VMs.

Comment: @JoeSewell  Yeah. I mean like a picture. But that was just as an example:)

Comment: If you want to view and edit a file in binary, you can find a number of free tools by searching for [hex editor](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=hex+editor)

Comment: Ok. Thank you @ChrisDodd . If you want you can make it to an answer and I will approve it :)